# How to align multiple images in a table cell vertically?

Tags: html, css, image, html-table, vertical-alignment

I am having 3 images that I need to center horizontally and vertically in a table cell. I am struggling aligning them vertically, they are stuck at the bottom. How should I do this?

[image]

I have created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sDLxt/).

My Html is:

```
<body>
    <br /><br /><br /><br />
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>aaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
            <td>bbbbbbbbbbbb</td>
            <td>cccccccccccc</td>
            <td>dddddddddddd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="toAlign" colspan="4">
                <img src="http://www.marietta.edu/News/images/Wikipedia-logo-small.gif" />
                <img src="http://luc.devroye.org/PhilippPoll-Wikipedia-logo-LinuxLibertine--Small.png" />
                <img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-CycORET_pXw/TjFcj6r-RoI/AAAAAAAAGLE/fyM10hArlBE/s1600/wikipedia_logo+SMALL.jpg" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>eeeeeeeeeeee</td>
            <td>ffffffffffff</td>
            <td>gggggggggggg</td>
            <td>hhhhhhhhhhhh</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

My CSS is:

```
table {
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: "Courier New";
}

#toAlign {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/sDLxt/1/

Apply the `vertical-align: middle;` to the `<img>`:

```
#toAlign img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: @JVerstry haha^^ I remember you from yesterday :-)